# How to extract specific data from JSON output based on today's date in python

Tags: json, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm accessing an API that allows me to pull employee time punches in and out during a given pay period. This JSON output is massive with a lot of data I don't need. All I really need from it is the employees Id number, their full name and their punches for just today's date.  However, the smallest dataset I can pull from is a full week. So if I want data for just today I need to filter out the other days of the week.

So far my method has been pulling the data I want into a dictionary: date_dict based on specific Key names.  Problem is the dictionary is filled with the key data for each day and I only want it if the time punches contain todays date. Below is an example output I achieved with my code and the code that generated it. Below that is the raw JSON data output from the API

```py
today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
parsed = "json data is here"

for item in parsed:
    date_dict={}
    date_dict['Employee']=item.get('Employee').get('EmployeeId')
    date_dict['EmployeeName']=item.get('Employee').get('FullName')
    date_dict['PunchInDateTime']=item.get('PunchInDateTime')
    date_dict['PunchOutDateTime']=item.get('PunchOutDateTime')
    print date_dict
```

```
{'Employee': u'080097', 'PunchInDateTime': u'2019-06-18T08:43:00', 'PunchOutDateTime': u'2019-06-18T13:43:00', 'EmployeeName': u'Peter Quill'}
{'Employee': u'080097', 'PunchInDateTime': u'2019-06-19T08:00:00', 'PunchOutDateTime': u'2019-06-19T09:16:00', 'EmployeeName': u'Peter Quill'}
```

```
[{
  "Id": 12970292,
  "Employee": {
    "Id": 346968,
    "Username": "starlord",
    "FirstName": "Peter",
    "LastName": "Quill",
    "Email": "starlord@email.com",
    "EmployeeId": "080097",
    "IsActive": true,
    "FullName": "Peter Quill",
    "ProfileMiniImageUrl": "https://buddypunchapp.blob.core.windows.net/profileminipics/new_employee_face2.jpg"
  },
  "LocationId": null,
  "LocationName": "",
  "JobCodeId": null,
  "JobCodeName": "",
  "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-18T08:43:00",
  "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-18T13:43:00",
  "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
  "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
  "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
  "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
  "PunchInIpAddress": "50.194.130.13",
  "PunchOutIpAddress": "50.194.130.13",
  "PunchInImageUrl": "",
  "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
  "Hours": 5.0,
  "RegularHours": 5.0,
  "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
  "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
  "PTOHours": null,
  "Duration": "05:00:00",
  "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
  "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
  "BreakMinutes": 0,
  "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
  "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
  "PunchOutLongitude": null,
  "PunchInLongitude": null,
  "PunchOutLatitude": null,
  "PunchInLatitude": null,
  "PunchInNotes": "",
  "PunchOutNotes": ""
}, {
  "Id": 12983841,
  "Employee": {
    "Id": 346968,
    "Username": "starlord",
    "FirstName": "Peter",
    "LastName": "Quill",
    "Email": "starlord@email.com",
    "EmployeeId": "080097",
    "IsActive": true,
    "FullName": "Peter Quill",
    "ProfileMiniImageUrl": "https://buddypunchapp.blob.core.windows.net/profileminipics/new_employee_face2.jpg"
  },
  "LocationId": null,
  "LocationName": "",
  "JobCodeId": null,
  "JobCodeName": "",
  "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-19T08:00:00",
  "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-19T09:16:00",
  "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4,
  "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
  "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4,
  "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager",
  "PunchInIpAddress": "50.194.130.13",
  "PunchOutIpAddress": "50.194.130.13",
  "PunchInImageUrl": "",
  "PunchOutImageUrl": "",
  "Hours": 1.267,
  "RegularHours": 1.267,
  "OverTimeHours": 0.0,
  "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0,
  "PTOHours": null,
  "Duration": "01:16:00",
  "PTOEarningCodeId": null,
  "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "",
  "BreakMinutes": 0,
  "BreakApprovalStatusId": null,
  "BreakApprovalStatusName": null,
  "PunchOutLongitude": null,
  "PunchInLongitude": null,
  "PunchOutLatitude": null,
  "PunchInLatitude": null,
  "PunchInNotes": "",
  "PunchOutNotes": ""
}]
```

Essentially I am getting this in my output:

```
{'Employee': u'080097', 'PunchInDateTime': u'2019-06-18T08:43:00', 'PunchOutDateTime': u'2019-06-18T13:43:00', 'EmployeeName': u'Peter Quill'}
{'Employee': u'080097', 'PunchInDateTime': u'2019-06-19T08:00:00', 'PunchOutDateTime': u'2019-06-19T09:16:00', 'EmployeeName': u'Peter Quill'}
```

and I want to get just this since the punches contain only todays date:

```
{'Employee': u'080097', 'PunchInDateTime': u'2019-06-19T08:00:00', 'PunchOutDateTime': u'2019-06-19T09:16:00', 'EmployeeName': u'Peter Quill'}
```

I just don't know how to get there since I can't just delete keys or values since there are duplicates and I do want the employeeid and fullname values. and I'd like to be able to do this for all employees in a given day so I can't hard code specific values either.

Edit:  This is some code later in the script that iterates through a dictionary and helps prepare a sql statement for inserting into a db.  Currently I just have it printing so I can verify it's working. However, when I run the new date_dict through it I get the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

```
timepunches_dict = date_dict

for i, punch in enumerate(timepunches_dict):
        punch_in = punch['PunchInDateTime']
        punch_out = punch['PunchOutDateTime']
        punch_in_sql = punch_in.replace('T', ' ')
        punch_out_sql = punch_out.replace('T', ' ')

        emp_id = punch['Employee']['EmployeeId']
        emp_name = punch['Employee']['FullName']

        if today in punch_in_sql:
            if i == 0:
            # ONLY RUN FOR FIRST ITERATION 
                print(emp_id, today, emp_name)

        # RUN FOR ALL ITERATIONS
            print(emp_id, today, i+1, punch_in_sql, punch_out_sql)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care the hours , you can split `'PunchInDateTime'` according to `T` and use in if condition:

```
for item in parsed:
date_dict={}
date_dict['PunchInDateTime']=item.get('PunchInDateTime').split('T', 1)[0]

if  date_dict['PunchInDateTime'] == today :
    date_dict['Employee']=item.get('Employee').get('EmployeeId')
    date_dict['EmployeeName']=item.get('Employee').get('FullName')
    date_dict['PunchInDateTime']=item.get('PunchInDateTime')
    date_dict['PunchOutDateTime']=item.get('PunchOutDateTime')
    print date_dict
```

Output :

```
{'Employee': u'080097', 'PunchInDateTime': u'2019-06-19T08:00:00', 'PunchOutDateTime': u'2019-06-19T09:16:00', 'EmployeeName': u'Peter Quill'}
```

Comment: That actually worked perfectly. I have a follow up question though. Later in the code I have a for loop that iterates through that output and will pull the values and insert them into a sql database.  When I feed in the 'date_dict' I get the error:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/micah/Desktop/Buddy Punch/employeeget.py", line 109, in <module>
    punch_in = punch['PunchInDateTime']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I'll had the code in the original post since I'm running out of space in this comment.